# How to set up a Django URL regex that accepts only 3 specific words?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have my urls.py set up as follow right now:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<content_type_name>[a-zA-z-_]+)$', views.content_type, name = 'content_type'),
]
```

This makes it so that this url will accept any word or string of words separated by - or _ or both. However, I want a regex that will accept only one of three words for the content_type_name parameter - 'comics', 'articles', 'videos'.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<content_type_name>comics|articles|videos)$', views.content_type, name='content_type'),
]
```

Comment: For django 2+ use `re_path` instead of `url`.